# How to change name of facebook fanpage using graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I was wondering, how do you go about changing the title/name of a fanpage using the Facebook API?

One guy told me he changed the name of his fanpage through the api very easily. But he only provided a link on his website to here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens

It doesn't mention anywhere how to change the name of a fanpage. I personally tried to change the other attributes of a fanpage by using https://graph.facebook.com with a post request but that didn't seem to work and just redirected to facebook homepage. Maybe because it needs to be done through PHP code?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all using the API.

Answer (score 3):

You cant change the fan page name with graph api...
You can only change the fields:

- about
- description
- general_info
- website
- phone
- Page Profile Photo
- Cover Photo
- Manage publishes

To do this, you need to use the page access token, you can get one, accessing the path '/USER_ID/accounts':

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100000903983008%2Faccounts

Comment: Well then how was this guy able to do it? http://www.nirgoldshlager.com/2013/01/another-stored-xss-in-facebookcom.html

Comment: No I'm asking how he was able to change the name of the fanpage? I'm looking to do some experiments.

Comment: You do realise that URL you provided is an article about Nir finding a security hole in Facebook, and receiving a payment for reporting it after it was fixed, right?

Comment: @Igy yes, but in the article he points to this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens  That page lacks detail on updating page name